# Do we need to import a package only to create an object or to call a method from that object as well?

Tags: java

```
class TestFormat
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

In the above simple code the `out` object is of type `java.io.PrintStream`. The `println()` method is also of class `PrintStream`. `PrintStream` resides in a different package then `java.lang` which is the default java package.

My question is how are we able to use method of a class from a package(`java.io`) we have not even imported? Granted that the object of that class is already provided to us but does that means that we need to import a package only to create an object of a class from that package and not to use its methods afterwards?

Thnax in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You misunderstand what import does.

Yes, you can use a class and its methods without an import statement.  It means that you'll have to type out `java.io.PrintStream` instead of using the short name `PrintStream`.

The *class loader* searches the classpath for a .class file when you first use a class;  *import* has nothing to do with this process.  It's just a way to save you from having to type out the fully resolved class name.

You can write Java successfully and *never* use an import if you wish.  You just need to be a good touch typist.

Comment: You could say, somehow, that it is similar to a forward declaration of a class in C++ as opposed to including the corresponding header file.

Comment: It's been too long since I last wrote C++, so I can't say whether that's correct or not.  My guess is "no", because import has nothing to do with forward declaration.

Comment: You are right, it is rather comparable to the "using" directive

Answer (score 0):

import is just saves you from typing total path if you import that class you are able to write PrintStream otherwise you have to write complete path java.io.PrintStream